# Deploying hybrid app sample in Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I am trying to run a hybrid app sample in Tizen 3 with no success.

I created both [native service](https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/native/AppFW/Hybrid_Service)  and [web app](https://developer.tizen.org/development/sample/web/Hybrid/Hybrid_Web_App) from samples. Then I added the service into web app multi package.
I verified that wgt file contains both webapp and native service files.

When web app runs in the device it can connect to the service but command messages do not reach the service. 
What I think the problem is that the service has moved into suspended state and so not responding to web app messages.
What am I missing to deploy hybrid app samples? 
Is there anything special (privilege or feature) I should add to force native service to stay awake to receive commands from web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after changing servie app id in web service!
Initially app.js has SERVICE_APP_ID in org.example.hybridservice format.
I changed it into xxxxxxxxxx.hybridservice where xxxxxxxxxx is web app id prefix. Same app id can be copied from tizen-manifest.xml file in .wgt file.

Comment: Yeah. Only after matching the namespace of the service id with web app id worked for me. However id in service app project's id in tizen studio doesn't matter.